# Expected 2D array, got 1D array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, sklearn-pandas

I'm running the following code from github, but I'm getting an error. What's wrong?

https://github.com/susanli2016/Machine-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Time%20Series%20ANN%20%26%20LSTM%20VIX.ipynb

Cell:

```
# scale train and test data to [-1, 1]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
train_sc = scaler.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = scaler.transform(test)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[17.24     18.190001 19.219999 ... 10.47     10.18     11.04    ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Try to make your data in proper order.

Comment: What is `train`? `pd.Series`? `np.array`? If it's a series, just use `.to_frame()`. If it's np array, reshape it as suggested `.reshape(-1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem adding the methods below, which apparently transform train and test objects to numpy arrays. Is that correct?

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
train_sc = scaler.fit_transform(train.values.reshape(-1, 1))
test_sc = scaler.transform(test.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The person who made that notebook was using a really old version of `sklearn`. In short, your features were of the form `[row_1, row_2...row_n]`, when they should have been of the form `[[row_1], [row_2]...[row_n]]`.

Accordingly, use this:

```
new_shape = (len(train), 1)

train_sc = scaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(train, new_shape))
test_sc = scaler.transform(np.reshape(test, new_shape))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I got a new error: `TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Comment: @grc probably gmds meant `(len(train), 1)`

Comment: @grc @RafaelC Yup, moved `new_shape` out into a separate statement and forgot to shift the brackets. Edited.

Comment: Thanks. Now it returns this ERROR: `Data must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: If I write like this, it works, but the "test_sc" is not working. `scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1)) 

train = train.reshape(1,-1)
train_sc = scaler.fit_transform(train) 
`